# Add new operations to the shiny application behind algorithm Apriori

Tags: r, shiny, scatter-plot, apriori, arules

I have this code (it works right):

```
library(shiny)
library(arulesViz)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel(""),

 tabsetPanel(
   tabPanel("Experiment 1",
      sidebarPanel(
        # Changed values of the widgets
          numericInput("supp", "Vložte hodnotu support", 0.01, 
                       min = 0.01, max = 0.8, step = 0.01),
          numericInput("conf", "Vložte hodnotu confidence", 0.01, 
                       min = 0.01, max = 0.8, step = 0.01))
  )
 ), 
  mainPanel(
     plotOutput("scatterPlot")
     )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data("Groceries")

    rules.all <- reactive({
    apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=input$supp, confidence=input$conf))
  })


 output$scatterPlot = renderPlot({ 
    plot(rules.all(), method = 'scatterplot')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I want to add these operations behind algorithm apriori:

```
quality(rules.all) <- round(quality(rules.all), digits=3)
top.support <- sort(rules.all, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA, by = "support") rules.sorted = sort(rules.all, by="lift")

subset.matrix = is.subset(rules.sorted, rules.sorted)

subset.matrix[lower.tri(subset.matrix, diag=T)] = NA

redundant = colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm=T) >= 1

rules.pruned = rules.sorted[!redundant]

rules.all = rules.pruned

rules.sorted = sort(rules.all, by="lift") 

rules.all = rules.sorted
```

to this code and then display scatter plot on the screen. Do you know to help me ? 
I want these rank:
1) do apriori on data ,,groceries,,
2) do operations on data ,,groceries,, (delete redundants asoc.rules..)
3) display scatter plot on the screen